# How to write extracted image from pdf to a file

Tags: java

Hopefully this is simple.

I am using pdfbox to extract images from a pdf. I want to write the images to a folder. I don't seem to get any output (the folder has read and write privileges).

I am probably not writing the output stream properly I think.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDXObjectImage;
public final class JavaImgExtactor
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Stuff();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void Stuff() throws IOException{
        File inFile = new File("/Users/sebastianzeki/Documents/Images Captured with Proc Data Audit.pdf");
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
            //document=null;
    try {
        document = PDDocument.load(inFile);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    List pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
    Iterator iter = pages.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
                PDPage page = (PDPage) iter.next();
                System.out.println("page"+page);
                PDResources resources = page.getResources();
                Map pageImages = resources.getImages();
                if (pageImages != null) {

                    Iterator imageIter = pageImages.keySet().iterator();
                    System.out.println("Success"+imageIter);
                    while (imageIter.hasNext()) {

                        String key = (String) imageIter.next();
                        PDXObjectImage image = (PDXObjectImage) pageImages.get(key);
                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/Users/sebastianzeki/Documents/ImgPDF.jpg");
                        try {
                            image.write2OutputStream(out);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing the output stream, and the file name is always the same.

```
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/Users/sebastianzeki/Documents/ImgPDF" + key + ".jpg") {
    write2OutputStream(out);
} (Exception e) {
    printStackTrace();
}
```

try-with-resources will automatically close `out`. Not sure whether `key` is usable as file name part.

Comment: I think its more fundamental than that as I don't get any System.out.println result after while (imageIter.hasNext()). Am I not adding the images to a collection?

Comment: @SebastianZeki Maybe the images are not on that level, or are inline images - you should share the PDF. Better: use the current version 2.0.6, and there use the ExtractImages.java source code from the source code download.

Comment: I recommend to use the ExtractImages from 2.0.6 and not the one from 1.8.* because the newer one catches more images.

Answer (score 0):

`image.write2OutputStream(out);` writes the bytes from the `image` object to the `out` `FileOutputStream` object but it doesn't flush the buffer of `out` .

Add it should do the job :

```
out.flush();
```